# pasar variable de la vista al factory angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Amigos, quiero enviar esta `id` que me imprime un `ng-repeat`

```
<p>{{ p.id }} </p>
```

a un factory para concatenarla en una url

```
    http://api/products/"+paramId+"?token="
             +localStorage.getItem('token')+"&user_id="+localStorage.getItem('user_id');

.factory('ProductosId',function($q, $http, $location){

   var Api = {};

    $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

    Api.productosId = function() {

        var defer = $q.defer();

        var paramId = $location.search().idp; 

        var urlaux = "http://api/products/"+paramId+"?token="
         +localStorage.getItem('token')+"&user_id="+localStorage.getItem('user_id');

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: urlaux,
        }).success(function(data) {
            defer.resolve(data);
        })
        return defer.promise;
    }
    return Api;
})
```

ya ahí esta hecho, enviandola por parametros y capturandola en el factory pero quiero hacer un método que me evite mandarla por parámetro porque no voy a usar otra vista si no un modal.

Answer (score 1):

Pásala por parámetros a la función desde esta forma

```
vista -> controller -> Factory
```

Para esto sólo tienes que modificar el Factory de esta forma

```
Api.productosId = function(paramId) {

    var urlaux = "http://api/products/"+paramId+"?token="
         +localStorage.getItem('token')+"&user_id="+localStorage.getItem('user_id');

    return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: urlaux,
    });
}
```

Por cierto habrás notado que he eliminado el deferred. Es que estas incurriendo en lo que se conoce como el [explicit construction antipattern](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html#the-explicit-construction-anti-pattern) o *antipatrón de construcción explicita*. No tienes que crear un deferred en tu código, el método `$http` ya te devuelve una promesa así que retornas eso mismo.

En tu controller declaras algo como esto

```
$scope.getById = function(paramId) {
    Api.productosId(paramId).then(function(response) {
        // Manipulas los resultados
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // Manejas el error
    });
};
```

y el tu vista, dentro del `ng-repeat` pones un botón o algo parecido y usas la directiva `ng-click`. Este es un ejemplo

```
<div ng-repeat="p in products">
    <p>{{ p.id }} </p> 
    <button type="button" ng-click="getById(p.id)">Enviar</button>
</div>
```